# Refraction and critical angle on a prism

Tags: refraction

I shouldn't be stuck on this, and I'm sure there's a simple way of doing this but can't seem to find it.
I am doing a problem Which involves a light ray entering a glass prism which is an isosceles triangle with refraction index $n_g$ and base angle $\theta$. The bottom is submerged in water with refraction index $n_w$. The ray enters the prism with an angle of $\pi/2-\theta$ and is refracted with an angle $\phi$ which is found by applying Snell's law 
$$\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)}=n_g \sin{\phi}$$
The ray is then reflected at the base of the prism with an incident angle of $\theta+\phi$ (which is found out with some simple geometry considerations).
In order for the ray to be reflected at the base, the condition is the following $$\sin{\theta+\phi}\geq \frac{n_w}{n_g}\implies\sin{\theta}\cos{\phi}+\cos{\theta}\sin{\phi}\geq\frac{n_w}{n_g}$$
$$\implies n_g \sin{\theta}\cos{\phi}+ n_g\cos{\theta}\sin{\phi}\geq n_w$$

$\implies n_g \sin{\theta}\cos{\phi}+ \cos^2{\theta}\geq n_w$ (using $\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)}=n_g \sin{\phi}$)

Knowing that $$\cos{\phi}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\phi}}=\sqrt{1-\frac{\cos^2{\theta}}{n_g^2}}$$
we can rewrite the inequality as follows:
$$\cos^2{\theta}+\sin{\theta}\sqrt{n_g^2-\cos^2{\theta}}\geq n_w$$

From here on I'm super stuck and I don't seem to simplify this any further as shown in the solution proposed in the image file.
[image]
Could you give me any hint on how to proceed?

Comment: Do the same thing with $\sin \theta$ as you did for $\cos \phi$

Comment: Then move $\cos^2 \theta$ to the RHS and square.

Comment: Whoa... That just took care of everything! I was squaring the whole thing but by moving the second l.h.s term to the right which made it very complicated.

Comment: No problem. Square roots don't play well with others. Best kept isolated.